# Linear Algebra: Vector Space (non example)

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors

In the set $V=\{x|x\in \mathbb R,x>0\}$, I know it is not closed under multiplication. But I am not sure how to prove or make counterexample in the addition property. Can anyone help explain this to me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as this set isn't closed under addition (there exists no inverse elements $y$ such that for every $x: x+y =0$), then it is not a vector space